# Initialize array of objects within constructor that include String class as parameter

Tags: c++

Here is the code

```
class Myclass{
 bla bla bla ...
  MyClass(int num,String name);
......
}
Myclass cs[2]={1,"kkkkk",(2,"99999")};
```

Whats wrong with this, when using the `String` object
I got compile error: `cannot convert const char* to int`

Comment: what is String? did you meant std::string?

Comment: `(2,"99999")` will have the same value as `"99999"` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the constructor properly. To use a constructor, do

```
Myclass(1, "kkk");
```

Comment: the class definition has two constructors

Comment: you only provided one

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the array of your class like myClass CS2, you cant initialize the object using '=' operator. All the object initialisation should be using constructors only.

```
myClass C=(1,"9999"); // Its wroung

myClass(1,"99999"); // It's true
```

If you want to stick with the usage of '=' operator. Then please do overload 'equal' operator in your class.